# ExecutorService with daemon threads - explicit shutdown

Tags: java, executorservice

If I set up an `ExecutorService` with a `ThreadFactory` that spawns daemon threads, do I still need to explicitly call the `shutdown()` method?

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setDaemon(true).build());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [as per `setDaemon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)),

> The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all
>   daemon threads.

So because you're using daemon threads your executor won't prevent your application from finishing. But that's not to say there's *no reason* to call `shutdown`. You may still want to prevent any additional tasks from being submitted at some point before your application ends.

---

Test it if you like: (I removed the Guava stuff, but the principal is the same)

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
        final Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.setDaemon(false); //change me
        return thread;
    });
    executorService.submit(() -> { while (true){ System.out.println("busy"); } });
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm using a ScheduledExecutorService to clean up a cache. At this point I won't bother shutting it down. Thanks Michael